# Upgrade process stuck

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

This pc has been running Ubuntu for sometime without hassles. This last week some of the services that I am running on the machine started failing. I logged into the machine using SSH.

Tried to run an apt update, but the process never seems to complete the download. It seems to get stuck and stops processing.
[image]

If I break the process, it seems to stop at another position, never at the same spot. The process stays in that position for more than an hour and never seems to complete.

I also tried to run an upgrade, when it gets to the generating a kernel I get the following error.

```
root@kodi:~# apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.7) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.7) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-41-generic
E: amd64-microcode: failed to create or prepend the early initramfs to the initramfs
/sbin/iucode_tool: 
/lib/firmware/intel-ucode: cannot open: No such file or directory
E: intel-microcode: failed to create or prepend the early initramfs to the initramfs
```

cpio: blank line ignored

I then tried to run `dpkg --configure -a` and I end up getting the same error.
How can I get this resolved.

Thanks
Lawrence

Comment: What is the OS? Is it Ubuntu?

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes it is Ubuntu 20.04

I read a little more and someone suggested that I do the following. "dpkg -P iucode-tool" below is the result.

root@kodi:~# dpkg -P iucode-tool
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of iucode-tool:
 intel-microcode depends on iucode-tool (>= 1.0).

dpkg: error processing package iucode-tool (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 iucode-tool

I have an additional possibility?
update the grub boot sequence, force an older kernel to restart. Then delete and reinstall?
Any ideas.

Comment: Try with : sudo apt-get -f install